# Flutter Checkbox wrong animation inside a ReorderableListView

Tags: flutter, checkbox, reorderable-list

I'm must doing something wrong, but when I reorder a checked checkbox inside a ReorderableListView, it is animating the unchecked tile:

[image]

Here a sample code that I'm using:

```
ReorderableListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
  children: <Widget>[
    for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index++)
      ListTile(
        leading: Checkbox(
          
          key: Key('$index'),
          onChanged: (v) => null,
          value: _items[index].isOdd ? true : false,
        ),
        key: Key('$index'),
        tileColor: _items[index].isOdd ? oddItemColor : evenItemColor,
        title: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
      ),
  ],
  onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    setState(() {
      if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
        newIndex -= 1;
      }
      final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
      _items.insert(newIndex, item);
    });
```

Full [code here](https://dartpad.dev/807ce6fa2707385fca195f19ba8b9760?null_safety=true)!

How can I do it properly?
Cheers!

Comment: I've just notice that if I use a GlobalKey() instead Key('$index') it keeps the Checkbox state, but I still need to understand what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you only need a key on `ListTile`, as they are the direct descendants of the `ReorderableListView`.

Second, the key needs to non-index-based. You can use `UniqueKey` or `GlobalKey`, but the best practice is to use a `ValueKey`, passing the value at that index.

In your case:

```dart
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final List<int> _items = List<int>.generate(2, (int index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index++)
          ListTile(
            leading: Checkbox(
              onChanged: (v) => null,
              value: _items[index].isOdd ? true : false,
            ),
            // here
            key: ValueKey(_items[index]),
            tileColor: _items[index].isOdd ? oddItemColor : evenItemColor,
            title: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
          ),
      ],
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            newIndex -= 1;
          }
          final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
          _items.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

As for why your indexed keys don't work - my understanding is that after the widget rebuilds (from reordering the list), your `ListTile` is keyed at the wrong index (because the index of that `ListTile` has changed). When you use the value, that is a constant that can be used to identify the widget.

Emily Fortuna on Medium has written a [wonderful article](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d) on keys that I would highly recommend reading if you are going to continue developing with Flutter.

Comment: Hey Alex, my bad I've just realised the wrong matching

Comment: No worries, if you think this question could be valuable to future readers I'd recommend accepting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've just realised my mistake, using key: Key('$index') is wrong because it is changing onReorder, so flutter is matching my old checked Checkbox value with the new unchecked Checkbox(My bad =|). Just use an ObjectKey in the ListTile and it will match correctly!

```
ListTile(
        leading: Checkbox(
          onChanged: (v) => null,
          value: _items[index].isOdd ? true : false,
        ),
        key: ObjectKey(_items[index]),
        tileColor: _items[index].isOdd ? oddItemColor : evenItemColor,
        title: Text('Item ${_items[index]}'),
      ),
```